# Interpretation of interaction effects in modeling

Tags: modeling, interaction

Let us consider the following variables:
Y=dependent variable and Xi=independent variables i=1,2,3,4 where X3 and X4 are categorical variables

Let us consider two scenarios as under:
Scenario 1: A model obtained as follows:

Y=b0 + b1*X1 + b2*X2 + b3*X3 + b4*X4

Scenario 2: A model obtained as follows:

Y=b0 + b1*X1 + b2*X2 + b3*(X3*X4)

What is the difference in interpretation for both the scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Model 1 is a model without interaction term, model 2 is a model with an interaction term but without the main effects. This is typically not what you want. Instead you want:

y = b_0 + b_1*x_1 + b_2*x_2 + b3*x_3 + b_4*x_4 + b_5*x_3*x_4

In that case the difference between the first model and the corrected second model is that without interaction term the effect of x4 is forced to be the same for each group represented in x_3, while with an interaction term you allow the effect of x_4 to differ with x_3.

For example, if x_3 is race and x_4 is university degree, than with an interaction effect you can look at the question if the effect of having a university degree is the same for whites, blacks, asians, etc. Without an interaction effect you force the effect of having a university degree to be the same for the different races.

Comment: So in this case if b_5 is significant then the effect of the degree is different for different races. Am I correct? How do I know if the effect is greater for Asians or for blacks?

Comment: if x_3 is race, than there will be multiple x_3s (dummies or indicator variables), and multiple interactions. ( I am typing with a baby on my lap who starts to want my attention, so this is all the detail I can give you )